# Offline session key agreement protocol

Tags: key-generation, key-exchange

Is there any **implemented** solution to agree on a session key in **offline** way.

I can exchange some keys before being offline but I need both sides to create the session key offline.

I need **implemented** and **secure** solutions.

Comment: You want to generate 2 symmetric keys on 2 disconnected clients? Sounds like OTP to me.

Comment: Something like that, but how to generate the same OTP  at both sides?

Comment: Use the same seed. Please look up the protocol.

Comment: So the seed agreement is problem! ;)

Comment: Then you need to clarify your requirements: how to generate 2 keys with no prior agreement to anything. I don't think anything has been implemented because it is impossible and still maintain a secure algorithm.

Comment: I can agree on a key before the offline phase but It must have ability to generate multiple session keys in offline phase.

Comment: Then seed agreement is not a problem

Comment: You're right! this is a solution.

Comment: Generating values based on a seed (and a CSPRNG) **can not be OTP**. Anything else than truly random, uniform and independent random values dooes not fullfill OTPs assumptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the information in the question and in the comments, this is pretty straightforward:

1. Online phase: Use any common key agreement protocol, e.g. [Diffie-Hellmann key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) to generate a shared secret.
2. Offline phase: Use a proper [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) on the shared secret and a nonce - one nonce for each key you need to generate. A counter would also work.

> I need implemented and secure solutions.

Both functionalities should be included in various cryptographic libraries.

For the security it is necessary to make sure that the shared secret is stored securely. But that's basic key management.

For the security proof you could argue that the KDF is actually a [PRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) or use the properties of [one-way functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family). A proof by contradiction should only take a few lines.